# Prove $A\cap A = A$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

How can $A\cap A = A$ be proved?

Here is my approach-

> $A \cap A$
>
> $= \{x : x \in A \cap A \}$
>
> $= \{x : x \in A \wedge x \in A \}$
>
> $= \{x : x \in A \}$
>
> $= A$

I curious to know if there exists more ways to prove the aforementioned statement apart from my approach ?

A detailed proof would be helpful.

Comment: Apply *Extensionality Axiom* : $\forall x (x \in Q \leftrightarrow x \in R) \to Q=R$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember that $$\boxed{M= N \iff M\subseteq N\;\; \wedge \;\; N\subseteq M}$$

Take any $x\in A\cap A$, then ($x\in A$ and $x\in A$) so $x\in A$ so $\boxed{A\cap A\subseteq A}$

And vice versa, say $x\in A $, then $x\in A\cap A$ so $\boxed{A\subseteq A\cap A}$

So $A\cap A =A$.

Answer (score 6):

You can just look at what intersection, i.e. $\cap$, produces for a set. Let $X,Y$ be sets, then

$$X\cap Y=\{z\mid z\in X\text{ and }z\in Y\}$$

Thus

$$A\cap A=\{x\mid x\in A\text{ and }x\in A\}=\{x\mid x\in A\}=A$$

Comment: @Aditya ... What?

Answer (score 1):

By the double inclusion theory, if $A \subseteq B$ and $B \subseteq A$, then $A = B$.

***$A \subset A\cap A$***

- Let $x \in A$.
- If $x\in A$ we have, in particular, that $x$ is an element of set $A$. Then $x \in A \cap A$, because $x\in A$ and $x\in A$ by the intersection definition. So $x \in A\cap A$;
- Therefore, $A \subseteq A\cap A$;

***$A\cap A\subset A$***

- Let $X \in A\cap A$.
- Then $x\in A$ and $x\in A$, by intersection definition. So, in particular, we got $x\in A$.
- Therefore, $A\cap A \subseteq A$.

Thus, by double inclusion, **$A\cap A = A$**

Answer (score 1):

Proof **using only set algebra laws** ( without analyzing the propositions in termes of set theoretic membership).

$A$

$= A \cap U $

$= A \cap ( A \cup A^c)$

$= (A \cap A)  \cup (A \cap A^c)$

$= (A \cap A)  \cup  ∅$

$= A \cap A$

Laws Used

$X \cap U = X$ ( and reciprocally)

$X \cup X^c  = U$ ( and reciprocally)

$X  \cap ( Y \cup Z) = (X \cap Y)  \cup ( X \cap Z)$

$X \cap X' = ∅$

$X \cup ∅ = X$

Answer (score -1):

The set $A \cap B$ is definied as $\{x: x \in A \text{ and } x \in B\}$

The set $A \cap A$ is, by consequence, $\{x:  x \in A \text{ and } x \in A\}$.

The set $A$ is obviously $\{x: x \in A\}$

Now, given any element $G \in A$, $G \in A
\cap A$, as the definition suggests.

Also, for any element $G \in A \cap A$, $G \in A$ has to be satisfied.

Thus, every element of set $A$ is also in the set $A \cap A$ and vice versa

That should be enough to declare the sets equal.

Comment: Why the down-votes? Can you tell me how to improve my answer?